# Understanding how Referential triggered actions work

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this problem regarding 3 tables, that is in my database.
Employee, Pharmacist, and Medicine

Employee id is the primary key and it is referenced by the pharmacist table through a foreign key. This key is references as a foreign key by the medicine table which depicts the pharmacist who added the new medicine

The problem is face is this. When creating the foreign keys I have used on delete cascade, so when I delete an employee the relevant rows are deleted from both the employee and pharmacist table, but at the same time in the medicine table the medicine that was added by that particular employee too get deleted.

I have tried using on delete set default by giving a default value to the columns that are referenced through the foreign keys

The result i expect, is when i delete a particular employee that employees details must be deleted from both pharmacist and employee table, but in the medicine table the column that depicts which employee added this medicine must change to user unavailable or removed from system

Comment: This sounds like you shouldn't be deleting employees, but marking them as no longer active. You can't have what you want with Constraints, because then referential integrity could not be maintained.

Comment: can you please explain as to marking them as no longer active means, is that something i should do using sql?

Comment: You would add a new column to your database, in the `Employee` table, perhaps called "IsActive` and probably using the datatype `bit` and set to `NOT NULL` and a default value of `1`. If the employee leaves, you then change the values to `0`, denoting they have left. Of course, you would need to update any queries as well to exclude employees who have a value of `0` for `IsActive`.

Comment: Oh okay ill give it a try